# Proper use of async

Tags: python, async-await

I have a `main` function that doesn't need to be async, but this function calls several other functions that do need to be async.

What would be the better practice: to make `main` async and call `asyncio.run(main())` in `if __name__ ...` or would it be better to not make `main` async (it has nothing to do while awaiting) and call `asyncio.run()` for each async function call made from main?

In other words, something like this:

```
async def func1():
    await something

async def func2():
    await something

async def main():
    x = input()
    if x == "y":
        await func1()
    else:
        await func2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Or this:

```
async def func1():
    await something

async def func2():
    await something

def main():
    x = input()
    if x == "y":
        asyncio.run(func1())
    else:
        asyncio.run(func2())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) said

> The asyncio.run() function to run the top-level entry point “main()” function (see the above example.)

That's mainly because of:

> This function cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is running in the same thread.

So, your first example with `asyncio.run(main())` is more Pythonic and should be used